# How to center content with CSS to work with Sticky Sidebar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My layout is made by Flexbox and I want to have a Sticky Sidebar that works great with content that overflows.

In my attempt, I'm using StickySidebar.js an external library. However, if you check the example because the Sidebar's `position` is set to `fixed` the content alignment is being messed up. I've also found out that centering the 2 elements with `justify-content` is what messes everything up.

```js
window.ResizeSensor = ResizeSensor;

new StickySidebar("#sidebar", {
    containerSelector: "#cont",
    innerWrapperSelector: ".sidebar-inner",
    topSpacing: 0,
    bottomSpacing: 20,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    maxWidth: "24rem",
    resizeSensor: true,
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tailwindcss/2.2.19/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/js/ResizeSensor.js"></script>
<script src="https://abouolia.github.io/sticky-sidebar/js/sticky-sidebar.js"></script>

<div class="flex justify-center mt-10" id="cont">
   <article class="max-w-xl border mb-10">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam ac turpis porta, tincidunt nunc in, facilisis sapien. Proin lobortis ac justo nec faucibus. Proin in egestas enim, in feugiat libero. Nulla quis vulputate ligula. Nulla tincidunt interdum augue, id ullamcorper dolor sodales eu. Phasellus sed libero lobortis, ornare neque et, ultricies quam. Praesent accumsan convallis mauris, sit amet convallis nibh feugiat nec.

Ut at faucibus tortor, eu suscipit tortor. Curabitur a molestie dui. Mauris ultricies rhoncus tellus id porta. Maecenas ultrices justo sit amet felis cursus, eget semper dui congue. Aenean maximus blandit nisl id commodo. In eget enim nunc. Cras sed vehicula urna. Integer non sapien cursus, scelerisque nunc non, imperdiet magna. In consectetur turpis sed felis laoreet, non bibendum tellus vulputate. Fusce eu tincidunt massa. Proin non imperdiet elit. Nulla nisi justo, egestas a viverra ut, suscipit non turpis. Vivamus mattis lacus a nisi varius bibendum. Sed non justo euismod, viverra felis vel, luctus nibh.

Pellentesque convallis ipsum nisl. Suspendisse potenti. Duis egestas maximus dui, ac accumsan purus euismod quis. Maecenas elit ante, iaculis vitae egestas a, fringilla sed ex. Suspendisse ac enim commodo, bibendum velit ac, sagittis purus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse fringilla ante et semper vestibulum.

Maecenas fermentum sagittis pellentesque. Ut semper enim id libero fringilla, ut malesuada velit cursus. Sed malesuada odio sit amet mauris dignissim tincidunt. Sed suscipit neque ut nibh auctor aliquam. Sed mollis lacus quis sollicitudin lacinia. Fusce vestibulum interdum commodo. Suspendisse aliquet venenatis nisl, at tempus dolor lacinia ac.

Quisque odio neque, accumsan eget laoreet a, lacinia nec arcu. Pellentesque faucibus purus gravida lorem pulvinar congue eget non erat. Morbi egestas arcu id justo tempor pharetra. Integer quis pharetra elit, at imperdiet turpis. Maecenas vitae gravida lectus, in ornare leo. Praesent porta non ligula a eleifend. Mauris nibh metus, blandit vitae metus quis, porttitor ultricies nunc. Nunc dictum consequat metus quis condimentum. Cras vitae interdum nisi, hendrerit placerat arcu. Nullam ut scelerisque urna, et pretium nibh. Pellentesque egestas elit egestas nibh tempus aliquam. Aenean vehicula velit eu est hendrerit, vel suscipit urna fermentum. Nam aliquam viverra augue ac pharetra.

Sed ut porta tortor. Nullam scelerisque lobortis neque eget auctor. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla tempor, nulla nec hendrerit laoreet, dui ex rutrum massa, vel scelerisque arcu sem eget libero. Vestibulum vestibulum odio vitae venenatis posuere. Phasellus pretium cursus ante, scelerisque iaculis nulla feugiat non. Integer varius posuere lorem, eget vehicula sapien commodo ut. Nam faucibus orci a magna blandit, a accumsan mi ornare. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent imperdiet sapien arcu, sit amet vestibulum eros iaculis ac. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Morbi luctus est a libero imperdiet, ac venenatis est blandit. Etiam pulvinar risus quis sollicitudin vehicula. Suspendisse lacinia neque non leo molestie, vitae volutpat velit laoreet. Vivamus purus nisl, aliquam id ullamcorper vel, egestas quis est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst.

Maecenas eu felis ut sapien mattis suscipit a et nisl. Etiam vel euismod dolor. Integer congue, metus in porttitor imperdiet, leo purus blandit tellus, ut dignissim odio eros sit amet mi. Duis malesuada feugiat felis vitae pharetra. Donec commodo metus sed luctus vestibulum. Ut eleifend eros nec metus venenatis hendrerit. Morbi commodo in magna a rutrum. Quisque sodales turpis eu felis lacinia pretium. Nam eu dolor sed magna gravida consequat. Fusce egestas lacus sit amet mi pharetra interdum. Donec lacinia pellentesque mi sit amet tincidunt. Integer id feugiat quam. Quisque congue a ipsum in sodales. Fusce tincidunt fermentum erat non molestie. Suspendisse sed ultricies augue.

Morbi massa leo, finibus vitae dictum quis, finibus ut purus. Maecenas convallis orci ac ante bibendum, ac tincidunt odio dictum. Cras placerat dapibus tellus, in porta risus. Donec vel tristique nibh. Vivamus euismod condimentum ipsum, sed fermentum nunc convallis id. Nunc laoreet scelerisque ligula, non consectetur orci sagittis vestibulum. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus varius nulla nec nulla viverra, eget auctor est ullamcorper. Fusce tristique sodales faucibus. Sed volutpat nec ipsum non facilisis. Aliquam eget urna mollis, vehicula mauris sit amet, vehicula sem.

Vivamus sit amet odio sed ipsum pharetra semper. Proin eu sagittis metus. Donec ut tempus velit, sed vehicula quam. Pellentesque ultricies maximus magna efficitur dictum. Nullam pellentesque rhoncus sodales. Sed enim ex, vestibulum in lorem a, scelerisque pretium lectus. Quisque sit amet ipsum ac lacus vehicula porttitor porttitor non nisi. Nullam a placerat lacus, eget varius massa. Phasellus dignissim suscipit sodales.

Praesent fringilla elit quis leo imperdiet, id accumsan ante consequat. Aliquam fringilla tortor eget posuere sollicitudin. Mauris imperdiet facilisis magna, eget ultrices elit vulputate at. Morbi scelerisque, ante in placerat rhoncus, nulla elit auctor odio, eu dapibus lorem nibh sed nisl. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Sed placerat quam vitae laoreet lobortis. Vestibulum blandit tellus in vulputate accumsan.

Nullam eget eros augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum elementum eleifend erat, sit amet pharetra nunc malesuada ac. Nunc dapibus lectus quis pharetra facilisis. Duis ut cursus dui. Morbi auctor volutpat laoreet. Sed eu accumsan arcu. Sed fermentum vulputate ante nec interdum. Phasellus in magna lectus. Mauris nec aliquet velit, sed laoreet odio. Vestibulum tincidunt iaculis varius. Ut lobortis nisi leo, a mattis ante vulputate ut. Sed molestie enim sed urna pharetra rutrum.

Fusce mattis maximus purus, nec aliquam dui rutrum placerat. Maecenas vel efficitur nisi, vel venenatis neque. Duis facilisis diam et ultricies condimentum. Duis gravida convallis sagittis. Pellentesque sollicitudin nisi sed ante porttitor tincidunt. Proin euismod metus nisl, ut convallis elit pharetra in. Nulla posuere, odio non tincidunt tincidunt, ex risus finibus leo, vitae semper ligula dui a arcu. Nam ac molestie odio. Cras quis dolor dictum, rhoncus nibh vitae, pretium eros. Nam ante urna, imperdiet non tortor vel, accumsan mollis urna. Fusce maximus pretium est vitae aliquam. Integer eu pharetra justo, sit amet pellentesque nunc. Nullam ultrices risus non felis ornare, vel vulputate augue lobortis. Aliquam urna mi, commodo eu elit ut, suscipit dictum nunc. Aenean viverra lorem vel vehicula malesuada.

Suspendisse nibh ex, facilisis non condimentum nec, ullamcorper scelerisque elit. Fusce at efficitur enim. Nullam sed facilisis diam, ut semper velit. Quisque tincidunt elit ex, nec fringilla enim lacinia sed. Pellentesque elementum et orci eget tempus. Duis posuere, tellus sed volutpat tempus, lacus mauris finibus neque, id suscipit leo est eu magna. Proin feugiat vulputate ante, vitae malesuada nibh. Fusce metus risus, tristique at tincidunt at, pharetra non lorem. Phasellus varius tellus non ullamcorper finibus.

Integer varius, nisl commodo tempor ultrices, orci nunc condimentum sem, volutpat porttitor magna lectus in nisl. Sed vehicula mauris vel ipsum viverra, sed dictum mi pretium. Nam blandit condimentum justo, rhoncus pharetra ligula consequat vitae. Curabitur felis mauris, dignissim eget tristique non, euismod nec sem. Etiam consequat ex a elit ultricies, in ornare odio egestas. Vestibulum vulputate lorem et tortor porta, eget condimentum lacus efficitur. Donec velit felis, dapibus non sollicitudin quis, eleifend id diam. Maecenas massa elit, fermentum a tincidunt quis, dapibus et dui. Vestibulum elit sapien, auctor eu consectetur vel, feugiat vulputate erat. Donec mi risus, sodales nec auctor vitae, placerat quis nulla. Nulla porta interdum blandit. Suspendisse potenti. Morbi sed consectetur velit. Nullam aliquam gravida ante, vitae pellentesque dui.

Fusce sodales finibus erat in lobortis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Maecenas semper diam et lorem ultrices, aliquet euismod purus pulvinar. Nullam porttitor ex eu sapien placerat, non rutrum arcu laoreet. Curabitur ut laoreet est. Nulla semper sem quis commodo congue. Suspendisse pharetra lorem eros, eget semper ex rutrum id.

Etiam sit amet interdum metus. Nam dictum auctor dui id eleifend. Integer faucibus tellus ac nibh commodo, nec efficitur massa luctus. Morbi ante quam, rutrum vel rhoncus venenatis, gravida quis lacus. Cras ac egestas felis, ut iaculis purus. Nunc venenatis ipsum dolor, vitae cursus quam lobortis eget. Proin bibendum rhoncus diam, vel porta nisi. Quisque placerat sodales dignissim.

Proin volutpat tortor ex. Suspendisse efficitur libero purus. Aliquam ornare ex elit, eu feugiat turpis bibendum scelerisque. Sed ut commodo enim. Nullam porta, ex ut luctus tempus, nunc ipsum hendrerit nisl, id lobortis urna turpis id leo. Nunc ultricies nisi tortor, sit amet efficitur dui gravida sit amet. Ut ac feugiat metus. Proin dictum, sapien in rutrum luctus, sem mi viverra sem, eget tincidunt est quam et arcu. Fusce scelerisque sapien sed odio scelerisque, ut dapibus ex commodo. Pellentesque id commodo ante. Donec ultricies aliquet cursus. Curabitur blandit tempor tellus eget auctor. Phasellus tristique aliquet ante eu facilisis.

Maecenas at metus diam. Nam nec congue sem. Donec lorem risus, sollicitudin ac augue sit amet, bibendum bibendum dolor. Duis lacus erat, facilisis quis lobortis vitae, elementum nec velit. Maecenas porta tristique mattis. Vivamus vitae dolor sit amet eros pellentesque sagittis. Aenean massa risus, luctus at nibh id, maximus blandit eros. Mauris vestibulum consectetur neque sit amet placerat. Curabitur fringilla aliquet ornare. Donec auctor odio fermentum dolor vulputate, ut ullamcorper erat eleifend. Sed pellentesque tristique rhoncus.

Aenean commodo convallis mi nec euismod. Donec vestibulum sem sit amet vestibulum lacinia. Phasellus consectetur tellus turpis, id tincidunt nulla tempus sit amet. Suspendisse nec venenatis libero, molestie mattis lectus. Ut ut risus quis nisl hendrerit convallis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Suspendisse ut nunc ultricies, ultrices est id, aliquet magna. Nulla auctor ligula nec metus finibus feugiat. Pellentesque sit amet pulvinar ante, vel semper magna. Aliquam in suscipit nulla, ut molestie turpis.

Sed scelerisque posuere lectus at tincidunt. Praesent at ornare nisi. Pellentesque mollis vehicula ante vel tempus. Sed sapien orci, bibendum ac purus at, faucibus interdum mi. Pellentesque feugiat gravida congue. Pellentesque mollis dictum sem, in posuere odio fringilla a. Duis urna libero, eleifend vitae erat in, pulvinar dignissim diam. Pellentesque luctus, tellus ut malesuada faucibus, ligula urna dictum nunc, non sollicitudin dolor lorem at est. Cras imperdiet, elit scelerisque convallis semper, augue erat posuere eros, ut sodales eros lorem at tortor. Nunc vel blandit massa. In nec sollicitudin nisi. Vivamus vitae ultricies orci, nec ultrices ante. Curabitur eleifend lorem eu nibh volutpat volutpat.

  </article>
  
  <article class="flex flex-col max-w-xs" id="sidebar">

     <div class="sidebar-inner px-4 border h-full" style="transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); will-change: position, transform;height: 800px;">
        Content for the sidebar...
       
       <div class="footer fixed bottom-0">
         botttom
       </div>
    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Is it possible to center everything in the middle while still using Flexbox and a fluid layout (with no container widths set)? Or are there any alternative solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

With css, you can center everything like this (if that's what you need)

```css
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 50%;
  transform: translate(50%,-50%);
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<span>text in the center</span>
```

Comment: Consider including a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help readers to better understand your solution.